# Looking to clean up a small ruby script

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for a much more idiomatic way to do the following little ruby script.

```
File.open("channels.xml").each do |line|
  if line.match('(mms:\/\/{1}[a-zA-Z\.\d\/\w-]+)')
    puts line.match('(mms:\/\/{1}[a-zA-Z\.\d\/\w-]+)')
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Thank you everyone for all the suggestions. I plan to give them all a try to help my understanding of Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original:

```
File.open("channels.xml").each do |line|
  if line.match('(mms:\/\/{1}[a-zA-Z\.\d\/\w-]+)')
    puts line.match('(mms:\/\/{1}[a-zA-Z\.\d\/\w-]+)')
  end
end
```

can be changed into this:

```
m = nil
open("channels.xml").each do |line|
  puts m if m = line.match(%r|(mms://{1}[\w\./-]+)|)
end
```

`File.open` can be changed to just `open`.

```
if XYZ
   puts XYZ
end
```

can be changed to `puts x if x = XYZ` as long as x has occurred at some place in the current scope before the if statement.

The Regexp `'(mms:\/\/{1}[a-zA-Z\.\d\/\w-]+)'` can be refactored a little bit. Using the `%rXX` notation, you can create regular expressions without the need for so many backslashes, where X is any matching character, such as `(` and `)` or in the example above, `|` `|`.

This character class `[a-zA-Z\.\d\/\w-]` (read: A to Z, case insensitive, the period character, 0 to 9, a forward slash, any word character, or a dash) is a little redundant. `\w` denotes "word characters", i.e. A-Za-z0-9 and underscore. Since you specify `\w` as a positive match, `A-Za-z` and `\d` are redundant.

Using those 2 cleanups, the Regexp can be changed into this: `%r|(mms://{1}[\w\./-]+)|`

If you'd like to avoid the weird `m = nil` scoping sorcery, this will also work, but is less idiomatic:

```
open("channels.xml").each do |line|
  m = line.match(%r|(mms://{1}[\w\./-]+)|) and puts m
end
```

or the longer, but more readable version:

```
open("channels.xml").each do |line|
  if m = line.match(%r|(mms://{1}[\w\./-]+)|)
    puts m
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed help John! I'll give your examples a go.

Answer (score 1):

One very easy to read approach is just to store the result of the match, then only print if there's a match:

```
File.open("channels.xml").each do |line|
  m = line.match('(mms:\/\/{1}[a-zA-Z\.\d\/\w-]+)')
  puts m if m
end
```

If you want to start getting clever (and have less-readable code), use `$&` which is the global variable that receives the match variable:

```
File.open("channels.xml").each do |line|
  puts $& if line.match('(mms:\/\/{1}[a-zA-Z\.\d\/\w-]+)')
end
```

Comment: Or use `Regex.last_match` instead of the obscure `$&`

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would probably just use the POSIX `grep` command. But there is `Enumerable#grep` in Ruby, too:

```
puts File.readlines('channels.xml').grep(%r|mms://{1}[\w\./-]+|)
```

Alternatively, you could use some of Ruby's file and line processing magic that it inherited from Perl. If you pass the `-p` flag to the Ruby interpreter, it will assume that the script you pass in is wrapped with `while gets; ...; end` and at the end of each loop it will print the current line. You can then use the `$_` special variable to access the current line and use the `next` keyword to skip iteration of the loop if you don't want the line printed:

```
ruby -pe 'next unless $_ =~ %r|mms://{1}[\w\./-]+|' channels.xml
```

Basically,

```
ruby -pe 'next unless $_ =~ /re/' file
```

is equivalent to

```
grep -E re file
```